# AJAX call for highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, highcharts

so I have finally came up with the following script that generates a highcharts graph based on data from MySQL.

The actual HTML and Javascript are here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function test(year){
   $.getJSON("data.php?year="+year, function(json){
   options.series[0].data = json['data'];
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
   });
 }
</script>
<script>
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("data.php?year=2012", function(json) {

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Revenue vs. Overhead',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Amount'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: json
        });
    });

});

});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<button onclick="test('2013')">2013</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP file then looks like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("x","x","x","x");
$year = $_GET["year"];
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = '2012';
$x = mysqli_query($con,"
    SELECT Logdatetime, Temp
    FROM alldata 
    WHERE YEAR(Logdatetime)=$year
    LIMIT 12"
);

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($x)){
$rows['data'][] = $r['Temp'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

?>
```

Now the problem is that what happens is that it works and generates the initial graph with a value "2012" as year, but after clicking the button which I wanted to generate 2013, nothing happens.

Any idea where the mistake is? It must be somewhere in the function test(), which I used to trigger the call from the button click, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities... enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: I know about this, this is just to test the AJAX function I will deal with security later on. Could you help me with triggering the ajax call with the "year" parameter?

Comment: you've hardcoded 2012 everywhere, including in your `.getJSON` call. you need to make that dynamic, e.g. `$.getJSON('data.php?year=' + year)`.

Comment: in the test function I have it like you suggested, so what should then be in the initial functino? Just data.php?

Comment: If you need full data at start, yes. Then cach click event, send request to php script which will return json, get json and use addSeries / setData functions.

Comment: go to the url http://yourhost/data.php?year=2013 and see the error/json. Its easier to debug that way